# Error durring editing functions.php (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I'm getting the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/humanityx/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/functions.php on line 1127

```
    /* Display the post meta box. */
    function smashing_post_class_meta_box( $object, $box ) {
        ?>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'smashing_post_class_nonce' ); ?>

    <p>
        <a class="post-btn-blue">Button</a>
        <br />
        <span class="short-blue">[buttonblue]Link Text[/buttonblue]</span>
        <br />
    </p>
    <?php
    }
```

I run the whole code in PHP Code checker and there is no problem. Also PHPStorm is not viewing any error.

https://pastebin.com/U45wqnpX

I have PHP 7.1

Comment: A full call stack for the error may be helpful in your case to determine what function or included file may be the problem. Add this https://pastebin.com/rEQF8E0w to you wp-config.php then past your /wp-content/debug.log

Comment: Still same.

[11-Oct-2018 08:44:15 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/humanityx/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/functions.php on line 1127
[11-Oct-2018 08:44:16 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/humanityx/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/functions.php on line 1127

Comment: My code editor is not seeing any error neither. Weird, but i can't try on a test website because i get a lot of errors. Have you tried to just remove this part from your function.php ? After what did it send you an error ?

Comment: Yes. Tried that too. Get unexpected end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents.....

In the function 'smashing_add_post_meta_boxes' you set the callback 'smashing_post_class_meta_box'.

According to the WordPress codex:

> $callback
>   (callable) (Required) Function that fills the box with the desired content. The function should echo its output.

When I look at 'smashing_post_class_meta_box' the function perhaps does not really 'echo' anything and therefore gives unexpected output resulting in the unexpected '}' not picked up by PHPStorm?

Like I said, not sure, could not test, but wanted to help.